# Downloading file from server Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my `index.jade` file I have

```
button(action="/download", type="button") Download Me!
```

and within my `index.js` I have

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/download', function(req, res){
  var file = __dirname + '/img/desktop-cover.jpg';
  res.download(file);
  console.log(file);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm trying, on click of the button, to initiate the `router.get('/download')` that will download an image I have.

I may of misunderstood some of the documentation and i'm not sure why it isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: "why it isn't working"— What is it doing? You're showing us the two extreme ends of the problem, but haven't described what actually happens, what the generated HTML looks like, if you get any errors or anything.

Comment: Sorry @Quentin I'm trying to download the file i'm passing through via `res.download(file);` so when I click on the button the action is `/download` that i've created a route for, and then the route will deliver a file

Comment: @GoodOldSnoopy but what is the error that's happening ? What happens when you try to download ?

Comment: Nothing, i've tried console logging it and get nothing back?

Comment: `console.log(file);` before `res.download(file);`

Comment: @SwarajGiri I console logged and don't get anything back

Comment: Thank you @MKA I have no idea why that didn't work? But once changed it to an `href` attribute I got a few errors with my image path and it downloads perfectly

Comment: Well, sorry for being a nub haha, thanks for the help! If you answer the question with your comment i'll mark as correct :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `button` tag don't have any action `attribute` try to replace it with `anchor` tag.

try to replace `button(action="/download", type="button") Download Me!`

with

`a(href='/download') Download Me!`